# Getting file name of file being received on the server

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a client/server program where I send a file over sockets. I create a file object in the server code, but I do not know what to call the file as the file the client sends is user-defined.

> NOTE: I want to be able to receive larger files e.g. `.mp3` files etc.

server code:

```
try{
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(123456);
    File myFile = new File(/* I dont know how to get the file name here*/);
    while (true) {
        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection accepted, ip - port - ");
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        sock.close();
        bis.close();
        servsock.close();
    }   
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: The client will have to tell the server how to call this batch of bytes...

Comment: @laune how can you do this?

Comment: Send a sequence of characters containing the name before you send the the data, and send the file size, too, as you can't call length on a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: You can create an Object to hold the file name and bytes on client and send this to server instead of sending only the file data and on server use the objectInputStream to get the same object " inputStream.readObject()" and type cast that to get the file name

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo to hold file name and  bytes

```
public class FileObject {
 private String fileName;
 private byte[] fileData;
  //getter/setters
}
```

Set the file name and data on clientSide

ClientCode

```
    FileObject fileObject = new FileObject();
    //set the fileName here
    fileObject.setFileName(fileName);

    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.isFile()) {
            //set data here
            fileObject.setFileData(fileBytes);
    } 
    //Now writing the FileObject object to socket

     outputStream.writeObject(fileObject);
```

ServerCode

```
 //Cast the received input stream to get data and file name
 fileObject = (FileObject ) inputStream.readObject();
```